# Does the new Google Drive client "Backup & Sync" have diff/delta uploading like Dropbox?

Tags: sync, dropbox, google-drive

Does the new Google Drive client "Backup & Sync" have diff/delta uploading like Dropbox?

[Introducing Backup and Sync for Google Photos and Google Drive](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/introducing-backup-and-sync-google-photos-and-google-drive/)

Comment: The new client works exactly how the old client(s) worked.  Google Drive does not have the support you are looking for.

Comment: Please include your question in the body of your question in the future, do not refer to the title, your question title needs some work to describe your question more accurately

Comment: @Ramhound Another thing that changed is that it doesn't support network drives anymore. Google Photo backup did.

Comment: That's just an Limitation of the client itself not the Google Drive cloud service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the new Google Drive client "Backup & Sync" have diff/delta
>   uploading like Dropbox?

It does not.  The only thing that changed was the client.  Google Drive as a cloud service does not support delta or differential syncing.

Comment: I've found [this random](https://datacenterpost.com/the-cloud-storage-providers-with-differential-sync-and-why-that-matters-by-sean-westbrook/) post where the author said exactly the opposite. Couldn't find an official source though.

Comment: @rraallvv - So submit an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty clear that Google still not implemented the block-level sync.
I wrote to them around beginning of 2017, their support team was almost unaware of what it is. So maybe not in their roadmap yet.
2 recent articles here:

1. [April 2018](https://www.cloudwards.net/dropbox-vs-google-drive/)
2. [August 2018](https://www.cloudwards.net/dropbox-vs-google-drive-vs-onedrive/#three)

OneDrive supports this feature, but only for Microsoft Office files (.docx, .xlsx, etc...).
And pay attention to security matters as I remember that Microsoft does not encrypt the data on server but only ciphers the transfer...
For now, Dropbox is the best option.